# Java How to find the sum of sum of the elements in two different arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, addition

I need to fill a new array, array3 with the sum of the corresponding elements in array1 and array2. The arrays are designated a1, a2, and a3.

```
double[] a1 = {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6};
double[] a2 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
```

a3 should also be an array of 5 doubles.
It should come out to be {2.2, 4.3, 6.4, 8.5, 10.6}.

I have tried to figure it out, but it keeps messing up. **Thank you** for any help!

Here is what I have so far:

```
double[] a1 = {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6}; 
double[] a2 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}; 
int i = 0; 
double [] a3 = new double[5]; 
for( i =0; i < a1.length; i++) {
   a3[i] = a1[i] + a2[i];  
}
System.out.println(a3[i]);
```

Comment: Your problem is about a IndexArrayOutOfBounds, right?

Comment: @RamonBoza Yes it is!

Comment: use Juned Ahsan answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double[] a1 = {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6};

double[] a2 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}; 

double [] a3 = new double[5];


for(int i=0; i < a1.length; i++){
    a3[i] = a1[i] + a2[i];
}
for(int i=0; i < a1.length; i++){
    System.out.println(a3[i]);  
}
```

This is a little bit better solution.  Anyway, the core of your problem is what you're doing with `i`.  When you're trying to iterate through the elements of `arrays` using `for` loops, keeping `i` scoped to just the `for` loop can help avoid some of the issues you ran into with your original question.

If you keep `i` scoped to just the `for` loops, then your compiler should throw a warning before you even try to compile because your original output statement would not even have known about a variable called `i`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to print all the elements of a3 array to see the desired result:

```
for( i =0; i < a3.length; i++){
     System.out.println(a3[i]);
}
```

Currently you are trying to display the result using one statement:

```
System.out.println(a3[i]);
```

which will throw null pointer exception because the value of i will be 5 at the end of loop.

Comment: What's wrong with `Arrays.toString`? And it won't throw an NPE it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider absoloutely no problem. I believe for the questionner it is worth learning how to use loops and arrays here rather than APIs :-)

Comment: It is ok for me, Boris, but then the OP will never know why he failed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider How does `Arrays.toString` print?  How does it separate elements of the array?  A space?  A newline?

Comment: @nhgrif you could always read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double[])).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Just remember variable i was incremented so to print last value, it must be i-1.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a1 = {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6};

        double[] a2 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

        int i = 0;

        double [] a3 = new double[5];


        for( i =0; i < a1.length; i++){
            a3[i] = a1[i] + a2[i];  
        }

        System.out.println(a3[i-1]);

        for( i =0; i < a1.length; i++){
            System.out.println("a["+i+"] = "+a3[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code enabled me to see exactly what was happening!

Comment: I have to have the [i-1] because as I had it before, it could only print the array up to index 4, right? So hence the outOfBounds exception really meant like an "under-bounds" in a sense?

Comment: `outOfBounds` means exactly that.  `Array` indexes start at `0` and go up to `n-1` where `n` is the total number of indexes in the array.  Trying to access an array index outside of this range is known as `outOfBounds`.  The "bounds" are between `0` and `n-1` for an array of size `n`.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
for( i =0; i < a1.length; i++){
  a3[i] = a1[i] + a2[i];  
}

System.out.println(a3[i]);
```

should be

```
for( i =0; i < a1.length; i++){
  a3[i] = a1[i] + a2[i];  
  System.out.println(a3[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is caused as the value of `i` in your print statement is equal to `a3.length()`. The elements of an array are indexed from 0 to `array.length-1`, not upto `array.length`. The rest of your code is absolutely fine. So, try this:

```
for( i =0; i < a3.length; i++){
     System.out.println(a3[i]);
}
```

or this

```
for( i : a3){
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

When printing the values in an array, you can use either of these two approaches, because `System.out.println()` does NOT print all the elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Guys already helped you with `IndexArrayOutOfBounds` caused by `System.out.println()`. Apart from this problem I would recommend change

```
double [] a3 = new double[5];
```

to

```
double [] a3 = new double[a1.length];
```

Otherwise, if you'll increase size of `a1`, you'll get another `IndexArrayOutOfBounds` error.